# when using insert into to load data into a column on sql, how do you exclude the null values?

Tags: sql, macos, sql-insert, azure-data-studio

i'm using azure data studio on a mac

i want to load data from another table into a new table i have created, the original tables columns contain some null values that my new table is not supposed to have.
how do i do insert into and exclude nulls?

```
insert into [Faculty].[Department](
    DepartmentName,
    DepartmentCode
)
select departmentName, departmentCode
from [].[]
```

but i want my new table to exclude nulls, i tried a where statement but that didn't work, please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what database you are using.Could you try below,

```
insert into [Faculty].[Department](
         DepartmentName,
         DepartmentCode
     )
     select departmentName, departmentCode
     from anothertable 
     where anothertable.col is NOT null
```